# Mocha --watch with Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mocha.js, tdd

I'm trying to use --watch on mocha but when I save code source or test source, it doesn't re run tests. I have an enviroment using docker-compose with `node:16-slim` image and my tests run inside it. This same config works with bare metal enviroment.

The dev docker image run the app with:

```
USER node
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

And this npm script is:

```
"dev": "npx nodemon --inspect=0.0.0.0:1080 src/index.js",
```

test npm script:

```
"test:tdd": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test mocha --config .mocharc.tdd.js",
```

.mocharc.tdd.js:

```
module.exports = {
    "reporter": "dot",
    "watch": true,
    "watch-ignore": [],
    "file": 'test/common.js',
    "recursive": true
};
```

output:

```
> test-app@1.0.0 test:tdd
> cross-env NODE_ENV=test mocha --config .mocharc.tdd.js
!

0 passing (6ms)
1 failing
1) Events
   abc:
 MissingParamError: Missing param: Data
  at updated (src/app/events.js:8:22)
  at Context.<anonymous> (test/app/events.test.js:13:28)

ℹ [mocha] waiting for changes...
```

Versions:

```
➜  test-app git:(master) ✗ npx mocha --version
10.0.0
➜  test-app git:(master) ✗ node --version
v16.15.0
➜  test-app git:(master) ✗ npx nodemon --version
2.0.15
```

What can I do to fix this? Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. I added `watch-files` attr to config file.

mocharc.tdd.js:

```
module.exports = {
    "reporter": "dot",
    "watch": true,
    "watch-files": ['test/**/*.js', 'src/**/*.js'],
    "watch-ignore": ['node_modules'],
    "file": 'test/common.js',
    "recursive": true
};
```